# Css box shadow lifted lower left corner

Tags: css

I have been trying to figure out how to lift the left corner of a div using box shadow for the past hour.  This is what I am trying to accomplish, number 3: http://www.paulund.co.uk/creating-different-css3-box-shadows-effects.  I know that there are posts that show you how to do it, but I have tried everything and nothing seems to work, which leads me to believe that something is wrong with my code.  I would appreciate any help in finding my error, thanks.

html

```
<img class='lazy image effect3' src='http://pearlsquirrel.com/images/lazyload.png' original-src='http://pearlsquirrel.com/profilethumbnails/$thumbnail' width='180' height='180' alt='PearlSquirrel'/>
```

css

```
.image {
-webkit-border-radius:2px;-moz-border-radius:2px;border-radius:2px;
position:relative;
padding:2px;
background:#fcfcfc;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
-o-box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px  rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px  rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.effect3
{
position: relative;
}
.effect3:before
{
z-index: -1;
position: absolute;
content: "";
bottom: 15px;
left: 10px;
width: 50%;
 top: 80%;
max-width:300px;
background: #777;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
 box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
-webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);
-o-transform: rotate(-3deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(-3deg);
transform: rotate(-3deg);
 }
```

This my sample in here : `http://jsfiddle.net/j4naA/`

Comment: Without access to the actual image being loaded (not "$thumbnail") your fiddle will not work.

Comment: Sorry for the late response.  Does this work?  http://pearlsquirrel.com/profilethumbnails/DJMediaz-08392713e56889a9fbbcaf7e18b2e331.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, I did my best to replicate the shadow at http://www.paulund.co.uk/creating-different-css3-box-shadows-effects .

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j4naA/19/

Html:

```
<div class="effect3" style="margin:20px;">
<img class="effect3" src="http://0777.ir/img/lndl.png"         
original-src="http://pearlsquirrel.com/profilethumbnails/$thumbnail" 
width="180" height="180" alt="PearlSquirrel"/>
</div>​
```

Css:

```
    .effect3
{
  position: relative;
}
.effect3:before
{
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  top: 80%;
  max-width:155px;
  max-height:18px;
  background: #777;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-4deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-4deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-4deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-4deg);
  transform: rotate(-4deg);
}​
```

Comment: I'm so sorry for the late response.  I've been studying for final and I have not been on in a few days.  This works perfectly.  You do not know how much help you have been.  Thank you so much!